# from weakly convergent sequence to strongly convergent sequence in a non-compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

> Is it possible construct a bounded linear non-compact operator $T:E \longrightarrow F$ such that maps from weakly convergent sequences of $E$ into strongly convergent sequences in $F$?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible if $E$ and $F$ are Banach spaces, and $E$ is reflexive.
The requested property is called complete continuity. Completely continuous operators are compact:

Every bounded sequence $(x_n)$ has a weakly converging subsequence, hence $(Tx_n)$ has a strongly converging subsequence. This shows that bounded sets are mapped by $T$ to sequentially relatively compact sets, which are relatively compact sets in the Banach space. That is, $T$ is compact.

Note that this does not apply to $l^1$, which has the Schur property that weak and strong convergence coincides.